# Github Desktop says my own local branch is "a protected branch" and I can not commit to it. How do I remove this protection?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I forked a Project on GitHub and then opened [my fork](https://github.com/nilslindemann/TiddlyWiki5) in GitHub Desktop (Windows 7). Locally, I created a branch and made changes to the code. Now I want to commit the changes, then publish the branch to my fork on GitHub, and then make a pull request to the original repo. That is how it used to work the last time I did this.

But now GitHub Desktop unasked protects this branch ("*branch* is a protected branch. Want to switch branches?"), and I can not commit things to it. On GitHub, in the settings of my fork, under "Manage Access", it says:

> 0 collaborators have access to this repository. Only you can
> contribute to this repository.

But I can not do this (contribute to this repository).

How can I "unprotect" that branch and commit to it?

Comment: "Protected" is a GitHub property, not a Git property. I don't use GitHub Desktop (that's something that's not Git; I use Git) but I imagine it has some way of fiddling with protectedness directly. If not, use your web browser to go to your GitHub repository, and poke around on those pages to find the "branch protections" settings. Find the protected branch, and de-protect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to first push the fresh branch without the commits to my fork at GitHub. After that the protection in GitHub Desktop disappeared, and I was able to locally commit changes to that branch and push them online.

I had to log off and log in once from within GitHub Desktop, to be able to push the branch, for security considerations, I had not logged in via Desktop for a while.